# Trying compile with makefile but say mkdir command not found

Tags: makefile, mkdir

When i compile i receive a error, but the command exist i tested my others projects and works using this same concept of makefile but now in this just dont work i dont know how to fix it, here is output from make command:

```
make:
mkdir obj
make: mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:42: obj/main.o] Error 127

make -w:
make: Entering directory '/mnt/c/project/philo/philo'
mkdir obj
make: mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:42: obj/main.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/project/philo/philo'
```

i dont know why this is appearing but even when a i do a make clean say the same thing to rm, help.

my makefile:

```
P_INCLUDE       =   include/
P_SRC           =   src/

P_OBJ           =   obj/

#Files
F_SRC           =   main.c dinner.c legacy.c

OBJ             =   $(addprefix $(P_OBJ), $(F_SRC:.c=.o))

INC             =   -I $(P_INCLUDE)
CFLAGS          =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror
PATH            =   mkdir $(@D)
RM              =   rm -rf
cc              =   clang

NAME            =   philo

all:            $(NAME)

$(NAME):        $(OBJ)
                @echo '.o created in obj folder'
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $(INC) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)
                @echo 'File(philo) created'

$(P_OBJ)%.o:    $(P_SRC)%.c
                $(PATH)
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g $(INC) -c $< -o $@

clean:
                $(RM) $(P_OBJ)
                @echo 'All clean'

fclean:         clean
                $(RM) $(NAME)

re:             fclean all

.PHONY:         all clean fclean re
```

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but right now you run `mkdir obj` for each and every object file. You don't need to do that. Instead change `PATH` to `PATH = obj`, make it the first dependency of `$(NAME)` (`$(NAME): $(PATH) $(OBJ)`) then add it as a target `$(PATH): /* no dependencies, newline and tab here... */ mkdir $@` (or something similar).

Comment: Also unrelated, but be ***very*** careful with `rm -rf`. Even the slightest mistake can make it erase your whole system. Use plain `rm` to remove all files in the directory, then `rmdir` to remove the directory itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have reset the `PATH` variable inside your makefile:

```
PATH            =   mkdir $(@D)
```

Now when you run a shell, your `$PATH` environment variable contains the text `mkdir foo` and so the shell will dutifully try to find the programs you want to run in the directory named `mkdir foo`, just as it would try to find them in `/usr/bin` if you had `PATH = /usr/bin`.

Since there is no directory `mkdir foo`, the shell cannot find any programs that it wants to run, including `mkdir`.

You should not modify standard system environment variables inside your makefile.  Maybe you want to use something like:

```
MKPATH          =   mkdir $(@D)
```

instead.